# Promisify is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

I am working on lex and I am trying to store user data in DynamoDB while using NodeJS

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

const uuidV1 = require('uuid/v1');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.saveBookingToDatabase = function(Arrival_city, Departure_city, Flight_type, Phone_number){
    console.log('saveBookingToDatabase');

    const item = {};
    item.bookingId = uuidV1();
    item.arrivalCity = Arrival_city;
    item.departureCity = Departure_city;
    item.classType = Flight_type;
    item.phone = Phone_number;

    const params = {
        TableName: 'airstallion',
        Item: item
    };



  const putAsync = promisify(dynamo.put, dynamo);

  return putAsync(params).then(() => {
      console.log(`Saving ticket ${JSON.stringify(item)}`);
      return item;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Promise.reject(error);
    });
  }
```

When i run the program is returning the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2NJp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since aws-sdk library supports promise, its not necessary to use `es6-promisify` library. Using node.js `async/await` we shall achieve the same use case.

```
'use strict';

const uuidV1 = require('uuid/v1');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.saveBookingToDatabase = async function(Arrival_city, Departure_city, Flight_type, Phone_number){
    console.log('saveBookingToDatabase');

    const item = {};
    item.bookingId = uuidV1();
    item.arrivalCity = Arrival_city;
    item.departureCity = Departure_city;
    item.classType = Flight_type;
    item.phone = Phone_number;

    const params = {
        TableName: 'airstallion',
        Item: item
    };

    try {
        let result = await dynamo.put(params)
        console.log(`Saving ticket ${JSON.stringify(item)}`);
    return item;  
    } catch(e) {
        throw (e)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks error reolve but new error is here (DeprecationWarning: Deep requiring like `const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');` is deprecated as of uuid@7.x)

Comment: The way uuid/v1 library required is deprecated in uuid@7.x library, update your module import as `import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';` For more info checkout this [link](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/master/README_js.md#deep-requires-now-deprecated)

Comment: Table is created but data is not showing in Dynamodb table and response is also successful

Comment: Can you pls inspect dynamodb response object , when there is no entry in the table, then there should be an validation issue or exception.